# Kitten fell ten feet to wood floor,

Tags: cats

does not appear to have broken bones but is hiding now. I put her in bedroom on bed and immediately ran under bed and hiding again.  we are far from any vet and the cost may not be worth it so how long should i wait

Answer (score 3):

Ten feet is enough for the righting reflex to do its job, meaning the cat would usually be landing on its feet.

If this was the case, you should monitor her movement and watch for any signs of sprains, e.g. the cat not putting weight on a specific leg, walking in unusual patterns, etc.

If this does not manifest in a few hours at most, then you can pretty much rule out injury to the limbs or hips.

Internal injury can't be ruled out, but is less likely compared to if the cat did land on the side.

---

If this is the case (cat landing on the side or back), you need to monitor for signs of injury on the sides and back, e.g. aversion to touch or even aggression when touched.

Again, this should manifest in a few hours at most.

Very important also is to watch for signs of internal bleeding or injury to internal organs, e.g. increased lethargy, loss of appetite, staggering or reeling walking patterns, etc.

This can be a bit insidious, as internal bleeding or organ damage may take a long time to manifest, and the symptoms often tend to creep in slowly instead of suddenly showing at full strength.

At least a few days should be closely monitored for any signs.

---

In case you did not observe the landing, or if you are unsure what you actually saw in that split-second, assume an imperfect landing, e.g. potentially landing on sides or back.

---

Regarding "cost for vet being worth it", if you are unsure I would consult with a vet via phone and always err on the safe side since injury treated early tends to be a lot cheaper than when it is already a life-threatening emergency.

Comment: Agree with all you've said, but in regards to "...always err on the safe side since injury treated early tends to be a lot cheaper than when it is already a life-threatening emergency." Please note late presenting injuries present *late*. How often does one hear, "If there are any problems such as x,y, or z), bring her back immediately. That's because not every injury can be detected on the initial exam. Still a solid answer, though.